# Why is my FriendBuy widget not embedding?

Tags: javascript, html, embed

I'm trying to embed a FriendBuy widget and even though it should be relatively easy and the code's showing in the source, the widget's not showing.

Here's the code from FriendBuy:

```
<script>
    window['friendbuy'] = window['friendbuy'] || [];
    window['friendbuy'].push(['widget', "cgi-gfp"]);
</script>
<div class="friendbuy-cgi-gfp"></div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Missing script tag to include some external JavaScript to use this or ad blocker perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for the answer - found the external JavaScript I needed. All fixed.

Answer (score 1):

For those whom might view this question:

It could also be that you didn't setup the configuration on the FriendBuy website. If you're deploying this on localhost to dev (say you're running rails), make sure to include the port number on the developer URL. It will NOT show up unless you designate the port number.

```
localhost
```

won't work as the developer URL, while

```
localhost:3000
```

will. So if you think you've got all the JS correct, check the FriendBuy config.